# Java decompiler meaning of Char - "\001"

Tags: java

We had to decompile and decrypt a file. When put into java decompiler i had a question.

There was a final `string decryptionkey = "something"`. And a function that had a loop over user input which checked whether
`userresponse.charat(i) - '\001' != decryptionkey.CharAt(i)`.
My question is what does the `- '\001'` do? if the decryption key is for example ABCD then logically the answer should be ABCD?

I've tried it but no luck. Am i missing something?

Comment: You showed the character in double quotes, which doesn't make sense. You can't subtract a string. If you mean ```'\0001'```, it's the integer value 1. The code is checking if the two `charAt` characters are lexicography adjecent.

Comment: You should show what happens when the character is `'\001', otherwise we can just throw guesses.

Comment: That is an octal character literal for the character U+0001 or SOH (Start Of Heading)

Comment: @khelwood fixed it. I mean userresponse.charat(i) - '\001'. Does lexicography adjecent mean that for example a = a in this case is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: You got the quotes wrong. You need single quotes  and then again - no quotes at all would make things a lot clearer.

So either you do this:

```
//userresponse.charat(i) - "\001" //wrong syntax
userresponse.charat(i) - '\001';
```

Or you do this:

```
//userresponse.charat(i) - "\001" //wrong syntax
userresponse.charat(i) - 1;
```

With that your question is simpler to answer. It takes the char in the userinput and subtracts one.

This is a very weak encryption. Every letter is encrypted to the letter bevor it in the alphabet. So "BCDE" is encrypted to "ABCD".

The first letter in the alphabet 'A' is special: while it is encrypted the same way, the letter prior to 'A' is not a letter but the '@'.  So "ABCD" would be encrypted to "@ABC". And to make it even clearer "EBCD" would be encrypted to "DABC".

```
userresponse.charat(i) - '\001' != ecryptionkey.CharAt(i)
```

Now that make more sense? It picks the letter at position i, then "encrypts" it and compares it with the letter in position i of the cypher "decryptionkey".

If you go through all letters and all match - the user did input the same plain text as was used to create the cypher "decryptionkey". In other words if one letter doesn't match the user got the wrong plain text. Thats what the "!=" is about.

Lets look at an example:

Say the user types in "BCD".

In the first step(i=0) it looks at the first letter "B" and subtracts 1 which gives 'A'. Now it compares that 'A' to the first letter in the decryptionkey.

In the second step(i=1) it would look at the second letter, which is 'C' and subtracts 1 which gives 'B'  and matches that against the second letter in the decryptionkey.

In the third step(i=2) it would look at the third letter, which is 'D' and subtracts 1 which gives 'C'  and matches that against the third letter in the decryptionkey.

If one letter doesn't match it should fails(hence "!=" ).

> So to the question "if the decryption key is for example ABCD then
>   logically the answer should be ABCD?"
>
> No! If the decryption key is
>   for example "ABCD" then logically the answer should be "BCDE"! As
>   every letter of the answer is subtracted by one.

Comment: Thanks, almost exacly what i needed. But for some reason ABC is actually BCD, i dont know why, your solution should work but no. But gave me enough clues to figure it out.

Comment: no, "BCD" gets encrypted to "ABC"  -> if the userinput is "BCD" it  matches the cypher.